# Order by two columns not using index in Oracle XE 11g

Tags: sql, indexing, oracle11g, oracle-xe

Why this simple query for retrieving first 100 rows, starting at given time, ordered by the time and primary key (`client_time` is not unique, that's why ordering by both), doesn't use the index?

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM requests
      WHERE client_time >= TO_TIMESTAMP('2017-07-01 10:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
      ORDER BY client_time ASC, transaction_id ASC
     )
WHERE rownum <= 100;
```

client_time is `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`, transaction_id is `VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)`.

Index I expect it to use is defined as

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_time_id REQUESTS (client_time, transaction_id);
```

Query execution takes ca 2 seconds (6 milion rows in my system, will be much more in production) and yields following plan:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation               | Name             | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT        |                  |   100 |   110K|       | 31237   (1)| 00:06:15 |
|*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY          |                  |       |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   VIEW                  |                  |   860K|   931M|       | 31237   (1)| 00:06:15 |
|*  3 |    SORT ORDER BY STOPKEY|                  |   860K|    65M|    86M| 31237   (1)| 00:06:15 |
|*  4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL   | REQUESTS         |   860K|    65M|       | 15294   (1)| 00:03:04 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### Predicate Information (identified by operation id):

```
   1 - filter(ROWNUM<=100)
   3 - filter(ROWNUM<=100)
   4 - filter("CLIENT_TIME">=TIMESTAMP' 2017-07-01 10:00:00,000000000')
```

When I remove the second part of my ORDER BY clause, this index actually is used and the query is executed in ca 1ms.

If I got [this Use the index, Luke](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/sorting-grouping/indexed-order-by) article right, shouldn't my query use this index too?

### UPDATE:

The plan after removing my second order column looks like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                     | Name             | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |                  |   100 | 65100 |   106   (0)| 00:00:02 |
|*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY                |                  |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   VIEW                        |                  |   102 | 66402 |   106   (0)| 00:00:02 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TRX_REQUESTS_LTZ |   102 |  8160 |   106   (0)| 00:00:02 |
|*  4 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN          | IDX_TIME_ID      |       |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So I believe the WHERE clause is not the issue here. Also, nothing changes after rewriting the WHERE like this:

```
WHERE client_time >= TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2017-07-01 10:00:00 +10:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that my index is built on `VARCHAR2` column. Because of NLS, the index order can't be used just like that to sort the result set.

Changing transaction_id to `NUMBER` resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the reason is the `WHERE` clause:

```
  WHERE client_time >= TO_TIMESTAMP('2017-07-01 10:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

You have specified that `client_time` is a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE`.  However, the constant is just a `TIMESTAMP`, without a timezone.  This means that the types need to be converted -- and that often thwarts index usage.

You should try using `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ()`, documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions194.htm).

Comment: Second part of my order by is the issue, without it, the index is used! I believe, what you are talking about, is the case, when the index can't be used, because oracle implicitly applies a conversion function. This is not the case. I tried your advice though. Like this client_time >= TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2017-07-01 10:00:00 +10:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM'). And it does not make any difference.